# Is the "runtimes" Edge/IE caveat for office add-ins planned to be fixed in the near future?

Tags: office-js

The third footnote [on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) notes that if you have a "Runtimes" element in your manifest, your add-in will run in an IE-based iFrame, even if your setup otherwise meets the requirements to run in an edge-based one. I guess I really have two questions here:

1. Now that IE11's EOL is rapidly approaching, are there any plans to do away with this caveat, so that if you meet the version requirements, you always get an edge-based web view?
2. What exactly do I lose by running in separate runtimes? The documentation states that "[using a shared runtime] creates limitations such as not being able to easily share global data, and not having access to all CORS functionality from a custom function," but I could really use some more details on what exactly that entails. Will I still be able to make CORS requests in custom functions? Still have the same domain for LocalStorage? Some clarification would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We're actively working to roll out Edge support for shared runtime this month.
2. Please see the [Runtime for UI-less Excel custom functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-runtime) article for details on current limitations.